# Converting date (age) into a number in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have made an age calculator to calculate the age of people participating in a test I'm making.
I need to use the age (year and month) to further down the line calculate their final score (a person between 5 year and 2 months would get a different score than a person who is 5 years and 8 months, even if they had the same amount of right answers.)

Is there any way to convert the age (5 years and 2 months) into a number I can use in an IF-statement?
E.g. =IF(AND(B6>5,0;B6<5,02);"TRUE";"FALSE")

[image]

Comment: Excel stores dates as the number of days since `1-Jan-1900`. Since years and months have varying number of days, I would suggest you use the days difference for the different scores and `VLOOKUP`.  In your example, days difference would be given by `="2010-3-1"` - `"2005-1-1"`

Comment: The problem here is how accurate you need it. *5 years and 2 months* may sounds exact, but it's not, because those 5 years could have 1 or 2 leap-years, and those 2 months could be any number between 59 and 62 days... I would follow @RonRosenfeld suggestion

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you! I will try this. I think it's the only way I can get a value that is accurate enough!

Comment: Glad to help. I'll post it as an answer so you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as the number of days since `1-Jan-1900`. Since years and months have varying number of days, I would suggest you use the days difference for the different scores and VLOOKUP for the different date ranges (in days). In your example, days difference would be given by. for example  `="2010-3-1" - "2005-1-1"`

Or, depending on how your original data is set up:

= test_date - birth_date

where `test_date` refers to a cell containing the full date, and the same for `birth_date`

If your original data is as you show in your screenshot, then you have to build the dates:

```
=DATE(B2,C2,D2) - DATE(B3,C3,D3)

-
```

Answer (score 1):

With the age in years in **A1** and the months in **A2**, in **A3** enter:

```
=A1+A2/12
```

[image]

This is a rough value that is "good enough" to compare the ages of two people if all you have is their ages in years and months.
*(the approximation assumes that one month is one twelfth of a year)*

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your age difference to number with
Try the formula =Value(Concat(B4,C4,D4))